# Find the number of records created in a certain range by one parent

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table in which recording from various modules of the system occurs.

The entry looks like this:

```
ModuleId  | DateTime        | OperationId
1          2020-03-15 21:00  4
1          2020-03-15 21:03  5
2          2020-03-15 21:04  2
3          2020-03-15 21:05  4
2          2020-03-15 21:07  5
3          2020-03-15 21:32  3
```

How can I find the Number of records generated in the interval of 15 minutes by one ModuleId, but with different OperationId?

Result:

```
TotalRecords | SatisfyingEntries
6             2
```

Example

```
1 | 21:15 | 1 this
1 | 21:17 | 3 and this is 1 interval
1 | 21:32 | 2 falls into the interval with the second record
```

Comment: Edit your question with sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: Add a few rows of sample data to make the questions clearer.

Comment: @TheImpaler , thanks, done

Comment: Would moments like 21:14 and 21:16 belong to the same interval or different one? Just to clarify `interval` meaning - is it absolute or relative.

Comment: @Arvo The interval is meant between the first record encountered, and if there is a record from it in the range of 15 minutes

Comment: Sorry, after reading your last comment and how you define "interval", a Calendar Table isn't appropriate. What do TotalRecords and SatisfyingEntries define?

Comment: @Shawn TotalRecords this is the total number of records, and SatisfyingEntries the number of records matching the condition

Comment: I don't know what your dataset looks like, but this may be a place to use a Quirky Update. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/solving-the-running-total-and-ordinal-rank-problems-rewritten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total entries is simple grouping result, no tricks here. For other part of your question, something like the next could work (not tested against boundary conditions):

```
select count(distinct moduleid)
from (
    select moduleid
    from log_tb t1
    where exists (
        select *
        from log_tb t2
        where t2.moduleid = t1.moduleid
            and t2.operationid <> t1.operationid
            and datediff(minute, t1.[datetime], t2.[datetime]) between 0 and 15
    )
) x
```

Comment: While _technically_ correct, I'm always cautious when using `BETWEEN` when it relates to dates. In this case it should be accurate, but there are so many opportunities for it to be weird. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I belive this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT ModuleId,COUNT(DISTINCT OperationId) AS number_of_records
FROM log_tb
WHERE DateTime >= sysdate - (15/1440)
GROUP BY ModuleId;
```

You can remove the GROUP BY adding another condition('=' or 'in ()', but I highly recommend the use of '=' if you need just one ModuleId )

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OperationId) as number_of_records
FROM log_tb
WHERE ModuleId = : ModuleId /*ModuleId in (ModuleId1,ModuleId2,... )*/ 
      AND DateTime >= sysdate - (15/1440);
```

sysdate could be another subquery with MAX so you will get 
the time for the first record for an specific ModuleId

Comment: This seems to be true, but what if I need to get similar data from a certain time range?

Answer (score 0):

If your total dataset isn't very large, you could go with a simple correlated subquery.

```
SELECT d.ModuleID, d.OperationID, d.datm
    , ( 
        SELECT count(*) 
        FROM d d2 
        WHERE d.ModuleID = d2.ModuleID
           AND d2.datm >= d.datm 
            AND d2.datm <= DATEADD(minute, 15, d.datm)
    ) AS SatisfyingEntries
    , ( SELECT count(*) FROM d d3 ) AS TotalRecords
FROM d
ORDER BY d.ModuleID, d.datm
```

But if this dataset is bigger than a few thousand rows, you may want to look at the Quirky Update I suggested above. Although they do slightly different things.

Note that this query calculates for the 15 minutes *AFTER* an event, so it isn't a true rolling 15 minute window. That's a completely different problem, that the Quirky Update should work with.

Also note that this query shows the need for good indexes on this table.

And final note: if 'TotalRecords' is always going to be a count of all records, you may be better off getting that in another query, depending on how you plan to consume this data.